# To get JVM GC logs, how do -verbose:gc and -XX:+PrintGCDetails differ

Tags: java, garbage-collection

When trying to get GC logs, i see -verbose:gc and -XX:+PrintGCDetails being used but i couldn't find any difference between these 2 options. How exactly do they differ?

Answer (score 1):

The verbose:gc logs contain valuable information about:

- List item
- GC pause times
- Frequency of GC
- Application run times
- Size of objects created and destroyed
- Rate of object creation
- Memory recycled at each GC

It can be combined with other HotSpot VM specific options such as -XX:+PrintGCDetails and -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps to get further information about the GC.

-XX:+PrintGCDetails 
Gives details about the GCs, such as:

- Size of the young and old generation before and after GCs
- Size of total heap
- Time it takes for a GC to happen in young and old generation
- Size of objects promoted at every GC

Comment: Does -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps add anything? I see timestamps displayed when using -XX:+PrintGCDetails alone.